# how to get the selected value of check-box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the select value of the check-box but it is always showing zero in the back-end table even when i select the check-box.  The data type for the check-box is bit.  I am not sure what am i doing wrong here

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into myTable(UserID, Name) values( @UserID, @Name)"))                                                                                            

                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", tempUser.ToString());

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", chckNM.Checked);

                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
```

here is the aspx:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chckNM" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Hve you tried chckNM.SelectedValue ?

Comment: @moe where are you checking in c# code for the checked value can you show the Method for the `chckNM` on Checked event..? `chckNM.Checked` is incorrect.. by the way you need `chckNM.SelectedValue`

Comment: it is not giving me that option "selectedvalue".

Comment: yes i am checking that in C# code as you can see in my post

Comment: @moe you are not checking it at all you are just writing chckNM.Checked which is not the same `chckNM.IsChecked` try that instead.. also Google is a really good tool if used properly.. check out MSDN on Checkbox as well

Comment: i was googling all day but what ever i try is not working..

Comment: I deleted my answer @moe because you need to provide the proper Parameters look at your code right here 
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", chckNM.Checked);` you are making this totally confusing and harder than it needs to be... 
how does `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into myTable(UserID, Name) values( @UserID, @Name)"))` relate to the `chckNM`..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use chckNM.IsChecked.Value to get the value.

Not sure why this didn't come up in your intellisense.

Comment: it is not coming up, i am not sure

Comment: I see your answer and an easier way would be to use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", chckNM.Checked ? True : False);

Answer (score 0):

i solved

```
if (chck.Checked ) 
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", True);
else
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", False);
```

Comment: That seems like a verbose way to convert a boolean value to the same boolean value.